# Responsive elements on Ipad

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design

I have a problem with the responsiveness of 4 elements on a site i'm working on  The pie chart elements scales perfectly on my desktop internet browser. But for some reason the elements overlap on the IPAD 2. I have used this CSS:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px)  
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
.q_pie_chart_holder {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Also the header image is cut off on the screen size.

```
   .elephant-header {
background-image: url("http://www.elephantdesign.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/header1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100%; 
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;
height: auto;

}
```

Does anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that there's a canvas element with a set width and height of 174px for those pie chart elements. You can check out the screenshot below to see where that appears.

So you have a couple of options:

1. Change the width of the canvas element and size of your pie charts. I think you're using this library - http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/ for your pie charts. It looks like the author assigns an inline `height` and `width` on the `<canvas>` element to resize it accordingly.
2. Change your column layout to have a two by two formation, i.e. use `vc_col-sm-6` for screens that are `768px` or smaller.

I didn't notice and issue with the header image - could you add a screenshot of where it's being cut off?

[image: screenshot of where the canvas element appears]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!! I'm going to try your solutions today. Herere's a screenshot of the top header being cut off: http://postimg.org/image/qqdkg31lf/ 

Help would be greatly appreciated! :)